# ClassNotFoundException while transforming XML

Tags: java, xml, xquery, transformation

When trying to transform a XML with XQuery, I get this error:
Full stack trace:(**only occures when running the test dynamically, static @Test works fine!)**

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at weblogic.xml.query.parsers.StAXCursorAdaptor.open(StAXCursorAdaptor.java:71)
    at weblogic.xml.query.runtime.InlinedXML.init(InlinedXML.java:63)
    at weblogic.xml.query.iterators.FirstOrderIterator.open(FirstOrderIterator.java:169)
    at weblogic.xml.query.runtime.constructor.SuperElementConstructor.prepOpen(SuperElementConstructor.java:168)
    at weblogic.xml.query.runtime.constructor.SuperElementConstructor.prepOpenElement(SuperElementConstructor.java:153)
    at weblogic.xml.query.runtime.constructor.ElementConstructor.open(ElementConstructor.java:91)
    at weblogic.xml.query.runtime.constructor.SuperElementConstructor.prepOpen(SuperElementConstructor.java:168)
    at weblogic.xml.query.runtime.constructor.SuperElementConstructor.prepOpenElement(SuperElementConstructor.java:153)
    at weblogic.xml.query.runtime.constructor.PartMatElemConstructor.open(PartMatElemConstructor.java:92)
    at weblogic.xml.query.runtime.core.LetIterator.fetchNext(LetIterator.java:128)
    at weblogic.xml.query.iterators.GenericIterator.next(GenericIterator.java:104)
    at weblogic.xml.query.runtime.core.LetIterator.fetchNext(LetIterator.java:133)
    at weblogic.xml.query.iterators.GenericIterator.peekNext(GenericIterator.java:163)
    at weblogic.xml.query.runtime.qname.InsertNamespaces.fetchNext(InsertNamespaces.java:160)
    at weblogic.xml.query.iterators.GenericIterator.next(GenericIterator.java:104)
    at weblogic.xml.query.runtime.core.ExecutionWrapper.fetchNext(ExecutionWrapper.java:88)
    at weblogic.xml.query.iterators.GenericIterator.next(GenericIterator.java:104)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.XqrlImpl$SegmentedIterator.nextSegment(XqrlImpl.java:1604)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.XqrlImpl.executeQueryToXmlObjects(XqrlImpl.java:1567)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.XqrlImpl.access$000(XqrlImpl.java:53)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.XqrlImpl$CompiledQuery.objectExecute(XqrlImpl.java:302)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Query.objectExecQuery(Query.java:80)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj.exec_query(Xobj.java:2525)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.execQuery(XmlObjectBase.java:525)
    at de.db.udg.componenttest.XQueryTester.transform(XQueryTester.java:574)
    at de.db.udg.componenttest.XQueryTester.test(XQueryTester.java:283)
    at de.db.udg.componenttest.XQueryTester.testBody(XQueryTester.java:182)
    at XQTest.lambda$null$0(XQTest.java:36)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestFactoryTestDescriptor.registerAndExecute(TestFactoryTestDescriptor.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestFactoryTestDescriptor.lambda$null$0(TestFactoryTestDescriptor.java:92)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestFactoryTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$1(TestFactoryTestDescriptor.java:91)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestFactoryTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestFactoryTestDescriptor.java:83)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.execute(MethodTestDescriptor.java:155)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.execute(MethodTestDescriptor.java:63)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$0(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:76)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$0(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:87)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:76)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$0(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:87)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:76)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:85)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:59)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamInputFactory
    at weblogic.xml.query.parsers.StAXFactoryHelper.<clinit>(StAXFactoryHelper.java:20)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamInputFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at weblogic.xml.query.parsers.StAXFactoryHelper.<clinit>(StAXFactoryHelper.java:17)
    ... 67 more
```

At this line:

```
 return Stream.of(arrayTuple4).map(
        tuple -> DynamicTest.dynamicTest("Testcase: " + tuple.a + " / " + tuple.b + " / " + tuple.c + " / " + tuple.d, () -> {

            if(tuple.c.contains("PAY")){
        here -->        Assert.assertTrue(new XQueryTester(tuple.a, tuple.b).testBody(tuple.c,tuple.d)); 

            }
            else{
                Assert.assertTrue(new XQueryTester(tuple.a, tuple.b).testHeader(tuple.c,tuple.d)); 
            }
        }));
```

My XQuery contains:

```
<fred:WERK>{fn:data($head/isi:WERK[1])}</fred:WERK>
```

I think this is caused due to the Array in my XQuery. However I can't find the Jar for weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamInputFactory, is there even one?

When running on my WebLogic Server it's all fine.

EDIT: When writing a static @Test without dynamicTest and lambda expression as in:

```
XQueryTester tester= new XQueryTester("...", "...");

AssertTrue(tester.testBody(..,..));
```

alls fine

**EDIT:**
My Transformer Engine:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.bea.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.bea.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>binxml</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.bea.core.xquery</groupId>
        <artifactId>beaxmlbeans-interop</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.bea.core.xquery</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans-interop</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.bea.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>xquery</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Solution:**
Using com.bea.core.utils.full_1.10.0.0.jar
and com.bea.core.weblogic.stax_1.10.0.0.jar

solved the problem.

Comment: no1 got a clue...?

Answer (score 0):

ClassNotFoundException means that the code you are running has a dependency on something that isn't on your classpath (in this case the class weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamInputFactory). The dependency might be in your own code, or in a library that you are invoking. It might be a static dependency (an explicit invocation from Java code) or it might be a dynamic dependency (e.g. loading the class identified by some system property setting.)

I don't know where the specific reference to this class is in your code, or where to find a JAR containing the class. But searching StackOverflow, or Google, for this class name shows quite a few other people with similar problems.

For starters, it would help to tell us which XQuery processor you are using.

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` only occurs for dynamic loading. Missing classes that are statically referenced cause a `ClassDefNotFoundError`.

Comment: As @SebastianRedl already said, this error occures when trying to run the test dynamically.
Edited my original post.